# raspberryPi g++: Ultrasonic sensor not working...!

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi, interrupt, raspbian

I wrote the following program for interfacing the ultrasonic sensor using g++ in raspberry pi Raspbian wheezy, using the wiring Pi libraries.However i couldn't make it work.Is there any problem with my code??? I want a continuous reading from the sensor...
Thank you in advance!!!

```
#include<iostream>
#include<wiringPi.h> 
#include<errno.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdint.h>       //for uint32_t
using namespace std;
uint32_t time1=0,time2=0;
int time_diff=0;
float Range_cm=0;

    void myInterrupt(void)
     {
       cout<<"Interrupt\n";
       time2=micros();
       time_diff=time2-time1;
       Range_cm=time_diff/58;
       delay(150);
       digitalWrite(2,0);
       delayMicroseconds(1);
       digitalWrite(2,1);
       delayMicroseconds(10);
       digitalWrite(2,0);
       time1=micros();

     }

     int main(void)
      {
           if(wiringPiSetup()<0)
            {
               cout<<"wiringPiSetup failed !!\n";
            }
          pinMode(2,OUTPUT);
          pinMode(3,INPUT);
          pullUpDnControl(3,PUD_DOWN);
          digitalWrite(2,0);
          delayMicroseconds(1);
          digitalWrite(2,1);
          delayMicroseconds(10);
          digitalWrite(2,0);
          time1=micros();

          if(wiringPiISR(3,INT_EDGE_RISING,&myInterrupt) < 0)
             {
                  cerr<<"interrupt error ["<<strerror (errno)<< "]:"<<errno<<endl;
                  return 1;
             }


           while(1)
             {
               cout<<"distance= "<<time1<<" "<<time2<<" "<<time_diff<<" "<<Range_cm<<"cm\n";
             cout.flush();
             }
            return 0;
        }
```

Comment: Is the `myInterrupt` function really running from a hardware interrupt? Interrupt functions should be simple and *fast*. Having delays in them is the opposite of fast. Preferably they just set a flag, and let the non-interrupt code check the flag and perform whatever actions needed.

Comment: As for your question, can you please be more specific? Just saying "it doesn't work" without saying *how* it doesn't work is not enough.

Comment: @indiv At least `volatile` and using an atomic would be a good idea then.

Comment: Create a global variable `volatile int num_interrupts = 0;`. Change the body of myInterrupt to a single line of code, `num_interrupts++;`. In your infinite loop in `main`, print out `num_interrupts`. Does it ever increment? If so, your problem is in your interrupt handler. If not, your problem is that your interrupt isn't happening.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ:  Thanks.  Volatile is rather important here so I deleted my comment and re-posted it.  Atomic increment you can do without unless you're really passionate about your debug count being accurate all the time.

Comment: Thank you guys for your help.Actually my problem was that, I couldn't get my interrupt triggered by hardware( i was using the echo Pin of HC SR 04 ultrasonic sensor).I found that out, using the method suggested by @indiv.

Comment: I found out my problem.I have posted the explanation below.

Answer (score 3):

The problem was with my placement of `wiringPiISR()` function. Since I placed it afterwards the initial triggering operation of trigger pin, I was missing the first echo signal as the `wiringPiISR()` was not setup yet. So the subsequent triggering and hence the echo was not taking place.The problematic code segment was

```
pinMode(2,OUTPUT);
pinMode(3,INPUT);
pullUpDnControl(3,PUD_DOWN);
digitalWrite(2,0);
delayMicroseconds(1);
digitalWrite(2,1);
delayMicroseconds(10);
digitalWrite(2,0);
if(wiringPiISR(3,INT_EDGE_BOTH,&myInterrupt) < 0)
  {
    cerr<<"interrupt error ["<<strerror (errno)<< "]:"<<errno<<endl;
    return 1;
   }
```

changing this segment to the following made the interrupt trigger

```
pinMode(2,OUTPUT);
pinMode(3,INPUT);
pullUpDnControl(3,PUD_DOWN);
if(wiringPiISR(3,INT_EDGE_BOTH,&myInterrupt) < 0)
   {
     cerr<<"interrupt error ["<<strerror (errno)<< "]:"<<errno<<endl;
     return 1;
   }
digitalWrite(2,0);
delayMicroseconds(1);
digitalWrite(2,1);
delayMicroseconds(10);
digitalWrite(2,0);
```

I modified the previous code accordingly, and finally I got the following code working nicely and measuring distance in cm.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<wiringPi.h>
#include<errno.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdint.h>       //for uint32_t
using namespace std;
uint32_t time1=0,time2=0;
uint32_t time_diff=0;
float Range_cm=0;
volatile int flag=0;
void show_distance(void);

void myInterrupt(void)
 {
    if(flag==0)
      {
            time1=micros();
            flag=1;

      }
    else
      {
            time2=micros();
            flag=0;
            time_diff=time2-time1;
            Range_cm=time_diff/58;
            show_distance();

       }

  }
void show_distance()
  {
    cout<<"distance= "<<time1<<" "<<time2<<" "<<time_diff<<" "<<Range_cm<<" cm\n";
    cout.flush();
    delay(1000);
    digitalWrite(2,0);
    delayMicroseconds(1);
    digitalWrite(2,1);
    delayMicroseconds(10);
    digitalWrite(2,0);

  }

int main(void)
  {
    if(wiringPiSetup()<0)
     {
       cout<<"wiringPiSetup failed !!\n";
     }
    pinMode(2,OUTPUT);
    pinMode(3,INPUT);
    pullUpDnControl(3,PUD_DOWN);
    if(wiringPiISR(3,INT_EDGE_BOTH,&myInterrupt) < 0)
            {
            cerr<<"interrupt error ["<<strerror (errno)<< "]:"<<errno<<endl;
            return 1;
            }
    digitalWrite(2,0);
    delayMicroseconds(1);
    digitalWrite(2,1);
    delayMicroseconds(10);
    digitalWrite(2,0);

    while(1)
    {
    }
    return 0;
 }
```